# C - accessing a structure array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm trying to code my own Turing machine. My program takes two files as arguments: my initial tape the machine will have to work with, and a rule file. This rule file consists in one rule per line, and each rule is five integers: current state, symbol found, new symbol, direction for the head to go, and new state. For that, I have a function that reads my file and puts each set of five `int`s found in a rule structure. An array of these structures is then generated.

What I'm trying to do is to return this array in order to be able to use it later on. Here is what I have :

```
struct rule {
    int cur_state;
    int symbol;
    int new_symbol;
    int direction;
    int new_state;
};
typedef struct rule rule;
struct vect {
    int nb_elem;
    rule *p;
};

vect rule_generator (char * file_rule){
    int line_number = 0;
    int ligne;
    char tmp;
    rule rule_list[line_number];
    vect output_rules;
    FILE * file;
    file = fopen(file_rule, "r");

    for(tmp = getc(file); tmp != EOF; tmp = getc(file)){
        if ( tmp == '\n')
            line_number++;
    }
    output_rules.p = malloc(line_number*sizeof(rule));
    assert(output_rules.p);
    output_rules.nb_elem = line_number;
    for (ligne = 0; ligne < line_number; ligne++ ){
        fscanf(file, "%d %d %d %d %d", &rule_list[ligne].cur_state, 
&rule_list[ligne].symbol, &rule_list[ligne].new_symbol, 
&rule_list[ligne].direction, &rule_list[ligne].new_state);
    }

    fclose(file);
    return output_rules;
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    vect rule_list = rule_generator(argv[2]);
    printf("symbole : %ls \n", &rule_list.p[0].symbol);
    return 0;
}
```

As some of you may already have guessed, this doesn't print anything... I've been scratching my head for a while, trying to access my array. I could really use a hand here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few problems here.

1. You are declaring array with size 0.

   `int line_number = 0;
    rule rule_list[line_number];`

   You don't need `rule_list` just remove it.
2. `output_rules` is no where being `initilized` other than memory allocating.

**Solution:**

I would suggest you to use `output_rules` for `fscanf`.

```
for (ligne = 0; ligne < line_number; ligne++ ){
        fscanf(file, "%d %d %d %d %d", &output_rules.p[ligne].cur_state, 
          &output_rules.p[ligne].symbol, &output_rules.p[ligne].new_symbol, 
          &output_rules.p[ligne].direction, &output_rules.p[ligne].new_state);
    }
```

---

Also did you mean to print the value of `symbol`?

As you are using `%ls` which is used to `wchar_t *`.

```
printf("symbole : %ls \n", &rule_list.p[0].symbol);
```

should be

```
printf("symbole : %d \n", rule_list.p[0].symbol);
```

Comment: Totally worked, thank you so much ! Looks like I kinda messed up in variable declarations here lol.

Answer (score 1):

There's lots going on here.

The main problem seems to be that this loop:

```
for(tmp = getc(file); tmp != EOF; tmp = getc(file)){
    if ( tmp == '\n')
        line_number++;
}
```

is going right the way through the file to the end, which means there's nothing left for `fscanf()` to read. If you want to read the whole file through once to find out the number of lines, and then read it again to read the content, you're going to have to either a) close and reopen it, or b) use the [`rewind()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rewind.3p.html) or [`fseek()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html) function to go back to the start of the file.

(To be honest, an even better solution would be to design your code so that you don't need to read the file twice over. If you end up trying this and get stuck, ask again with a new question on this site.)

In addition, you should add these lines at the beginning of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
```

to read in the header files which define the functions you're using, and put this line after your `struct vect` definition to define the type:

```
typedef struct vect vect;
```

Also, *please* run your compiler with warnings enabled. This would have helped you find some of these problems yourself!

Comment: Hi 
thanks for your answer ! For the includes, I didn't put them here on purpose, in order to give you guys something a bit cleaner to look at. 
I didn't know I had to rewind the pointer, I guess that makes sense, you make me feel dumb lol, thank you so much !
Also, as for typedef  : struct vect vect; I seem to have forgotten to copy/paste it from my code, my bad :D

Comment: @Bruh Glad that helps! For next time you ask a question, please reduce your *code* to as little as possible which shows the problem, and then post *all* that code. This way bits which you don't know are important are included, and we don't have to guess which bits you're showing us, and which bits yo're not. There's some really helpful advice on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
And don't feel dumb - everyone starts somewhere! Good luck!

Comment: Lastly, remember that if you like this answer and the other answer on this page, or in fact any answer on the site, you can click the "up" arrow to vote for them as "useful answers".

Comment: it says I have a too low reputation  so it doesnt display my vote :p i guess i need to be more active

Comment: @Bruh My mistake. You need fifteen reputation to vote up. There you go, now you have it. :-) https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges